# Volume 2 of Apostol's Calculus, section 8.17 exercise 12.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

awesome community! I'm asked to prove that if $\nabla f (x,y,z)$ is always parallel to $(x,y,z)$, then $f$ must map $(0,0,a)$ and $(0,0,-a)$ to the same number. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: observe that parallel means that all partial derivatives must be proportional to the variables. For example
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=\lambda  z 
$$
that is $f $ must have a quadratic term in $z $ and so on for the other variables.